# How to pass multiple sprites as a Single sprite between two Activities in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I have a background images, on which there is a table (sprite) is placed. On table sprite there are flowers placed. I want to make all these sprites a Single sprite and pass then to next activity.
Is it possible? If so how/?>
If not how can I solve this issue??

Answer (score 2):

Store all the sprites you want to send in a Sprite array (Sprite[]), or a list if you prefer. Then add the resultant array to your intent that you use to launch your next activity by calling putExtra(String name, Object object) on the intent. Then you can grab it in the next activity.

For more info see: [How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

Comment: are your sure this will work? Because on finishing previous activities its texture atlas and regions will not be available any more. And spite is region and texture actually.